# Converging Sequences Definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Q. Explain exactly what it means for $\{a_n\}$ $n\in\mathbb N$ to converge to $L ∈ R.$

I wrote that for $\{a_n\}$ to converge to $L ∈ R$ means that the infinite sequence $\{a_n\}$ has a limit $L$ where no matter how small $ε > 0$ you choose, from a certain $n$ onwards, the absolute difference $|L - \{a_n\}|$ between $L$ and $\{a_n\}$ is always less than ε.

Am I on the right track? Is there anything else that needs to be added?

Comment: Well, your thinking is correct, but your notation is slightly off. People usually write that $a_n \to L$ when, for any $\epsilon >0$, there will be some integer $N$ such that whenever $n \geq N$, $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Just to clarify on the notation remark, $\{a_n\}$ typically refers to the sequence as a whole, whereas $a_n$ refers explicitly to the $n^\text{th}$ term. The former is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, whereas the latter is an element of $\mathbb{R}$ (and hence we can subtract $L$ from it and take its absolute value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\{a_n\}$ converges to $L \in \mathbb R$" and "$\{a_n\}$ has the limit $L \in \mathbb R$" mean the same thing. The point of convergence is called the limit, so to say a sequence is convergent is the same thing as saying it has a limit. However, as you go further down the chapter, you will learn about "limit points", and this notion will clash slightly with the notion of limit, because saying "$\{a_n\}$ has a limit $a$" and "$\{a_n\}$ has a limit point $a$" will mean two different things. For this reason, I think you should stick with "$a_n$ converges to $a$" rather than "$a_n$ has limit $a$" in writing/speech.

The definition is actually very fine. However, when you write $|L - \{a_n\}|$ you must be careful : the notation $\{\cdot\}$ denotes a sequence , and when we refer to a *term* of that sequence, then we remove the bracket. A sequence(of real numbers) is a function from the natural numbers to the real numbers : a term of the sequence is a single real number. We don't know how to subtract a sequence from a real number : we know how to subtract a real number though. Therefore, $|L-a_n|$ is the right notation  to be used there.

Besides this, I find your definition to be suitable.